# Flutter: Custom Widget not showing elements

Tags: android, flutter, custom-widgets

I Created Custom Widget (cardChild) but it's not showing any element

```
class ReuseableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReuseableCard({required this.colour, required this.cardChild});
  Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
```

Icon And Text both not showing in app

```
                Expanded(
                  child: ReuseableCard(
                    colour: activeCardColour,
                    cardChild: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                          size: 80.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Male',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Color(0xFF8D8E98)),
                        )],
                    ),
                  ),),
```

No Error in flutter
And please tell why widget require "required" will constructing.

Comment: try putting the "@" symbol in front of the word "required"

Comment: Showing Error suggesting to remove @

Comment: before your semi colon, add this

Comment: : super(key: key)

Comment: so, ```class ReuseableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReuseableCard({required this.colour, required this.cardChild}) : super(key: key);
  Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild; ```

Comment: Getting error in key: key

Comment: could you edit your question to show us more of your code? I can't quite see where your stateless widget ends as there is no end parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ReuseableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReuseableCard({required this.colour, required this.cardChild});
  Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: cardChild,    //Here 
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        color: colour,
      ),
    );}
}
```

We need to add cardChild in Container.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will solve you issue..

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({Key? key, required this.argumentWidget}) : super(key: key);
  
  final Widget argumentWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          argumentWidget,/// this widget is come from FirstRoute screen as you can see we are on second route screen
          customMyWidget(stringData: 'myNameIsFlutterDev'),//this is from your class 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  // the below widget is your customWidget inside the class
  
  Widget customMyWidget({required String stringData}){
    return Text(stringData);
  }
}
```